# Is there any REST API in Elasticsearch for deleting indices on the basis of index creation date?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using time based indices to store log data in elasticsearch on daily index basis. 
I am looking for the best approach to delete indices which are greater than 30 days old. 
Is there any API in elasticsearch that returns the list of indices created during a given time period.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you name your indices?

Comment: error-logs_2016-12-29. Time format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Then I suggest using the [official curator tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) for doing this.

Comment: Can you share any reference that mentions how to use this tool in AWS Elasticsearch?